# What is delphichromiumembedded for?

Tags: delphi, browser, tchromium

Is this an internet browser component? that is more than the capability of TwebBrowser?
Im using TWebBrowser, and so if Im logged on to a website then I run my Delphi webbrowser to the site, I was already logged-on also, BUT if I logged-on to Mozilla firefox and run my Delphi webBrowser(TwebBrowser) it doesnt know if Im logged-on to the website from mozilla, TwebBrowser only integrate in internet explorer.

Does this Chromiumembedded also can integrate to mozilla or chrome?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It embeds a Google Chrome browser control in a Delphi form.

TWebBrowser is an embedded Internet Explorer control. It might have access to cookies and other data from your Internet Explorer settings, but it won't have access to any other browsers' settings, including Firefox and Chrome.

The embedded Chrome browser will not have access to the user's Chrome or Firefox settings. Those are entirely separate applications, and *your* application doesn't get any special standing related to them just because it's using an embedded browser control. If you want to gain access to another application's settings, you'll have to do it the same way anyone else does.

Answer (score 2):

`TWebBrowser` uses the rendering engine of Internet Explorer, and shares several of its settings (like cookies).

`TChromium` uses the rendering engine of Chromium (which is the open-source part that Google Chrome is based on), and operates independently.  It can't read Firefox's cookies, nor, AFAIK, Chrome's.